# call a servlet onload from a GWT application

Tags: java, gwt

I need to read database properties from server.xml and need this information on load of the page.How do I acheive it in GWT ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there is anything specific to GWT. But I guess you could use

[Servlet.getResourceAsStream](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/products/products/servlet/2.3/javadoc/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29)

Or if you use JSP, you could use the `application` implicit object to get the `ServletContext` and you can use `getResourceAsStream`

Some pointers [here](http://www.exforsys.com/tutorials/jsp/jsp-implicit-and-session-objects.html) and [here](http://groups.google.com/group/Google-Web-Toolkit/browse_thread/thread/f8e339331dc1e57?pli=1)

Answer (score 0):

In your onModuleLoad() call an RPC through a

```
DeferredCommand.addCommand(new Command() {
    public void execute () {
      getDBParameters();
    }
  }
```

where getDbParameters is a method that populates the values for you by calling an RPC.

See http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication.html for how to communicate with server.

On the Server side just have your RPC return a HashMap of properties and read those.